# UninstallString being set with /I not /X param

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an MSI that I build dynamically with a WiX script that is being installed fine. However, the UninstallString consistently has a /I ("slash-eye") param to msiexec.exe which I would expect to be a /X. I read about the UninstallString [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and it says that this registry entry is set by the Windows Installer. What would I be passing to the Windows Installer either via WiX or the install command I issue that would cause an UninstallString to always have the /I ("slash-eye") param?

Comment: Where are you seeing this UninstallString?  Are you seeing it generated by Add/Remove Programs? ( Programs and Features? )  FWIW  msiexec /i foo.msi REMOVE=ALL and msiexec /x foo.msi are mostly equivilant.   Are you experiencing a problem related to this?

Comment: I am seeing the UninstallString in the registry's Uninstall key for this MSI's product code. I am experiencing a problem related to this. When we go to remove the MSI, it is reinstalling itself and it consequently never goes away from Programs and Features list.

Comment: I suspect your problem lies elsewhere because Add/Remove programs doesn't actually use the UninstallString listed in the Uninstall\{ProductCode} key.  It uses the MSI ProductCode property instead.   Enable logging and log an uninstall and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: This is just a (highly educated) guess:  But I'd look to see if you have any custom actions that are scheduled for uninstall that are failing and rolling back the uninstall.   An uninstall log would show you.

Comment: We are using "msiexec /x product_code_here /qn /l*vx uninstall.log" to do the uninstalls. Does that change anything for you in your thoughts? We don't use uninstall from any UI, all done headless and via a console application.

Comment: You'd have to post a log for review.

Comment: New information...it appears that this UninstallString is being set after the initial install - without uninstall being in the picture at all. msiexec exits with 0 (MainEngineThread...is returning...0) at the end of the setup.log file we have.

Comment: The ModifyPath value in the Uninstall registry key is also using /I, not /X.

Comment: I would hope so. /X means uninstall and a modify isn't an uninstall.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. Any comment on the other note?

Comment: I guess the base question here is what am I sending to Windows Installer via my MSI *during the initial install* that causes the UninstallString to have that /I param?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I broke down and spoke with MS support on this. The answer is to set the ARPNOMODIFY property in the MSI to 1 to generate an UninstallString that uses the /X parameter.

The /I param means that you have the "Change" and "Repair" options available in appwiz.cpl listing. Hope this helps someone else facing this issue.

The below MSDN articles describe the ARP properties in detail.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367590(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367591(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367592(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Still sounds like a bug that UninstallString and ModifyPath are always identical.

Surely ModifyPath should have /i and uninstallString have /x?

Comment: @MichaelParker: It is.

Answer (score 2):

You must create a ARPAltRegistryEntries component in your WiX installer to set the UninstallString.  Setting the parameter to /I instead of the expected /X allows you to use your own uninstall UI.  Here is an example:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
    <!-- Create alternative ARP entry that lets us launch uninstall with
        full UI.  Setting ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT above hides WI generated key
                that uses the product GUID.-->
    <Component Id="ARPAltRegistryEntries" Guid="">
        <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Your Product"                                      Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">                   
            <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="UninstallString" Value="MsiExec.exe /i[ProductCode] REMOVE=ALL"/>
        </RegistryKey>
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: While I think this answer is useful, I do not wish to tamper with a setting that should be handled by the Windows Installer - if the documentation  I referenced in the original post are to be believed. I really want to understand what about my particular MSIs are causing the Windows Installer to generate this UninstallString.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asked for Wix projects but if somebody is using setup project of visual studio then one of the solution is to add a post build vb script to change ARPNOMODIFY to 1 as suggested by @joe Baltimore

1. Create a VB script file as follows "setnomodify.vbs":

```vb
    Option Explicit

    Const msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact = 1
    Dim argNum, argCount:argCount = Wscript.Arguments.Count

    Dim openMode : openMode =  msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact

    'This script adds a type 51 custom action into a given MSI database that
    'ensures the ARPNOMODIFY is set to 1


    ' Connect to Windows installer object
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim installer : Set installer = Nothing
    Set installer = Wscript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer") :
    CheckError

    ' Open database
    Dim databasePath:databasePath = Wscript.Arguments(0)
    Dim database : Set database = installer.OpenDatabase(databasePath, openMode) : CheckError

    ' Process SQL statements
    Dim query, view, record, message, rowData, columnCount, delim, column

    query = "INSERT INTO `Property` (`Property`, `Value`) VALUES ('ARPNOMODIFY', '1')"
    Set view = database.OpenView(query) : CheckError
    view.Execute : CheckError

    database.Commit

    If Not IsEmpty(message) Then Wscript.Echo message
    Wscript.Quit 0

    Sub CheckError
      Dim message, errRec
      If Err = 0 Then Exit Sub
      message = Err.Source & " " & Hex(Err) & ": " & Err.Description
      If Not installer Is Nothing Then
        Set errRec = installer.LastErrorRecord
        If Not errRec Is Nothing Then message = message & vbLf & errRec.FormatText
      End If
    Fail message
    End Sub

    Sub Fail(message)
      Wscript.Echo message
      Wscript.Quit 2
    End Sub
```

2. Add this script path as post build event of the installer project with proper folder path as follows :

**PostBuildEvent = cscript "$(ProjectDir)setnomodify.vbs" "$(BuiltOuputPath)"**

Now whenever you build the installer setup project ARPNOMODIFY would be set to 1 and 
Unistallstring of the installed application will have "/X" instead of a "/I" in registry

You can also do this manually by using ORCA and adding ARPNOMODIFY as 1 in "Property" table of MSI.